# how i can save multi rows in mvc for same model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have model lets call it staffmodel 
which had Id -Name -ordernum properties 
and mvc razor i create table by html to display all staff and in the end of table lets say i have 2 buttons
add button and save button 
for each click on add it should create new row that allow to me to add new employee data 
and save to save the new entry 
trick here i want to add more than 1 row and then save em all by 1 click 
staff model

```
 public class staffmodel
{ [DisplayName("الكود ")]
    public int? staffID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("الأسم ")]
    public string staffName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int departmentID { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("الترتيب ")]
    public int? staffOrder { get; set; }

}
```

staffcontroler

```
 [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Create")]
    public ActionResult Create_get()
    {
        departmentBL department = new departmentBL();



        ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(department.getDepartments(), "departmentID", "departmentName");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Create")]
    public ActionResult Create_post(int DepartmentId)
    {

        staffmodel staff = new staffmodel();
        TryUpdateModel(staff);
        staff.departmentID = DepartmentId;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            staffBL staffcreator = new staffBL();
            staffcreator.addStaff(staff);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        return View();
    }
```

razor code

```
    @model Overtime.Models.staffmodel

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12">

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DepartmentId,"أختار القسم", new { @class = "dropdownList col-xs-5 col-xs-pull-3", })
            @*@Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", (SelectList)ViewBag.DepartmentId)*@

            <table class="gridtbl">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.staffName)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.staffOrder)
                    </th>
                    <th>

                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="tblrow">

                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.staffName, new { @class = "form-control",autocomplete="off" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.staffName)

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.staffOrder, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.staffOrder)
                    </td>


                    <td>


                        <i class="fa fa-times eleremove   faa-wrench animated-hover animated-hover"></i>


                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table> <i class="fa fa-plus-square add"></i>
            <br />
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="أضافة" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" />

            </p>

        }
        <div class="pull-left back">
            @Html.ActionLink("العودة الى الرئيسية", "Index")
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"></i>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

finally jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("form").on("click", ".add", function () {

    var row = ($(".tblrow").html());
    $(".gridtbl").append("<tr class=tblrow>" + row + "</tr>")

});
$(".gridtbl").on("click", ".eleremove", function () {

    if ($(".gridtbl tr").length > 2)
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    else {
        alert("لا يمكن حذف هذا الصف. صف واحد على الأقل  ")
    }
});
```

});

how i can loop through all rows and insert em to my db ?!

Comment: I create a JSON payload with all the rows i want saved, make sure there is a C# model to match it and $.ajax() a POST to the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorporating javascript like above would make the code less readable and complicated.
I suggest that you create one partial view for your row.
This partial view would use a view model which would contain all the elements from the row, along with the validations.

When you click the add button, then make an ajax post and append this partial view at end of the table.

To save these rows, make sure you write the custom model binder.

Please refer this http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/ in order to accomplish the functionality you are trying.

Thank you.

Comment: actually its great article i tried the sample but i always face a problem after appending the new row and try to post the collection it see Model object in razor is null :(

Comment: Did you include your newly created HTML helper in the correct web.config as mentioned?

If possible, just post a link to your code, then we can investigate further.

I have personally tried the code given in that blog and it worked for me.

Comment: thanx aloot i figured out the problem i named the para in post action not the same in BeginCollectionItem thanx aloot for you help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ICollection<staffmodel>`, to receive it in your **Controller**, and you can go with `foreach` to save it.

And in your view you need to create the inputs as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="[0].staffmodel.staffName" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="[0].staffmodel.departmentID" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="[1].staffmodel.staffName" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="[1].staffmodel.departmentID" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="[2].staffmodel.staffName" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="[2].staffmodel.departmentID" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

You do that with `jquery`, be careful the inputs, should always start at 0.

Comment: well i cant get ur idea in ur sample is a good soliution for fixed number for controls created by jquery but in my case its not fixed number do u think i go with for loop ?!